# ASP.NET MVC 5 JsonResult & Ajax - MVC JQuery error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Thanks to @NikhilGhuse, which solution have been sent to me (please mark his answer). I can apply this solution to my data these are the results and the keys:

First of all my model need to send a List to the controller. This is my my function to send the List:

```
                            public List<VistaModelo> SegundaConsulta()
                            {
                                //Web.Config
                                Entities db = new Entities();

                                var consulta = from varLocal in db.LecturaContadorLuzAANDRES
                                                group varLocal by varLocal.dispositivo into subconsulta
                                                select subconsulta.OrderByDescending(t => t.unixtime).FirstOrDefault();

                                List<LecturaContadorLuzAANDRES> lista = consulta.ToList();

                                List<VistaModelo> listaVistaModelo = new List<VistaModelo>();


                                foreach (LecturaContadorLuzAANDRES b in lista)
                                {
                                    VistaModelo objLista = b.pasaObjetoAVistaModelo();
                                    listaVistaModelo.Add(objLista);
                                }

                                return listaVistaModelo;
                            }
```

Then in my controller I need two functions:

Consulta 6. Read the list and transform to JSON (you need: using Newtonsoft.Json; in the controller:

```
public JsonResult Consulta6()
    {
        var Consulta = new ConsultaContraBD();
        List<VistaModelo> miSegundaConsulta = Consulta.SegundaConsulta();

        return Json(miSegundaConsulta, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); //El JsonRequest Behaviour permite que se devuelva información de JSON en un getRequest.

    }
```

Consulta7. From this method I make the View:

```
public ActionResult Consulta7()
    {
        return View();

    }
```

Finally I need Ajax into the script to read the information pass to method Consulta6. Note: Remember to load the packages json2.js and jquery-3.0.0.js

```
                            @{
                            ViewBag.Title = "Consulta7";
                        }



                        <script src="~/Script/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
                        <script src="~/Script/json2.js"></script>
                        <script type="text/javascript">

                            $(function () {
                                $('#btonLista').on("click", function (e) {
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                    $.ajax
                                        ({
                                            url: '/Home/Consulta6/',
                                            type: 'get',

                                            dataType: 'json',
                                            success: function (data) {

                                                $(data).each(function (index, item) {
                                                    $('#ulLista').append("<li>" + item.consumo + "</li>")
                                                });
                                            }
                                        });
                                });
                            });
                        </script>
                        <div>
                            <input type="button" id="btonLista" value="Click" name="" />
                            <ul id="ulLista"></ul>
                        </div>
```

The final result is a page where you click a button and returns the list.

Comment: remove this  var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(miSegundaConsulta);

Comment: Well,what element pass to return Json(??, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); ?

Comment: `return Json(miSegundaConsulta, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`, and your missing the backslash in the closing `</li>`

Comment: @StephenMuecke. Tranks for </li> but if I use your suggestion: return Json(miSegundaConsulta, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  I do not receive any table or data when I push the bottom. Besides I do not receive any error in the browser.

Comment: do "console.log(data)"  on success. Then let us know about result of this

Comment: @StephenMuecke I can able to see Consulta52()

Comment: @PowerStar When I change this:
success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        $(data).each(function (index, item) {
                            $('#ulLista').append("<li>"+item.consumo+"<li>")
                        });

I receive in the browser: 
[{"dispositivo":"ContadorLuz1","unixtime":1501686708,"consumo":16},{"dispositivo":"ContadorLuz2","unixtime":1501686712,"consumo":11},{"dispositivo":"ContadorLuz3","unixtime":1501686713,"consumo":15},{"dispositivo":"ContadorLuz4","unixtime":1501686715,"consumo":14}]
and the previous error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function ()
    {enter code here
        $('#btonLista').on("click", function (e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax
                ({
                    url: '/Home/Consulta52/',
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $(data).each(function (index, item) {
                            $('#ulLista').append("<li>"+item.consumo+"</li>")
                        });
                    }
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

My two controllers:

```
public ActionResult Consulta51()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult Consulta52()
    {
        var Consulta = new ConsultaContraBD();
        var miSegundaConsulta = Consulta.SegundaConsulta();


        return Json(miSegundaConsulta.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

/// My Sample Starts here

//Controller

```
     namespace Sample.Controllers
    {
       public class HomeController : Controller
    {
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult Consulta52()
    {
        modelCS model = new modelCS();
        List<Department> ds = model.getList();
        return Json(ds, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
   }
 }
```

//Index.cshtml

```
     @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
  }
  <h2>
      Index</h2>
  <script src="../../scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js" type="text/javascript">
   </script>
       <script src="../../scripts/json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function () {
    $('#btonLista').on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax
            ({
                url: '/Home/Consulta52/',
                type: 'get',

                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {

                    $(data).each(function (index, item) {
                        $('#ulLista').append("<li>" + item.DepartmentName + "</li>")
                    });
                }
            });
         });
       });
  </script>
       <div>
        <input type="button" id="btonLista" value="Click" name="" />
       <ul id="ulLista">
     </ul>
      </div>
```

And My Model Class goes like this

```
    public class modelCS
     {
    string constr = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=test1;Integrated Security=True";
    List<Department> newDept = new List<Department>();
    public List<Department> getList()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        // SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Department", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Department", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        var td = ds.Tables[0];
       // List<Department> newDept = new List<Department>();

        foreach (DataRow t in td.Rows)
        {
            newDept.Add(new Department() { DepartmentId = (int)t.ItemArray[0], DepartmentName = t.ItemArray[1].ToString() });
        }

        return newDept;
        //List<string> list = listT
    }

}
```

Department class

```
public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
}
```

[image: OutPut]

Comment: You need to give some description also not only code.

Comment: it is understandable that whatever we are getting from that method we are converting it to a list and when we will return in to ajax success we can apply for each to this returned data

Comment: it is not mandatory to convert ` miSegundaConsulta.ToList() `  you can do that in ajax success also

Comment: apparently no. Issue is due to serialization conflict with .net and js

Comment: Your answer is not correct. If I use your answer, I push the button and I do not receive any error, but I do not visualize any table neither data in the browser.

Comment: can you share your method contains in model

Comment: This is just an example which might help you in recognising your mistake

Comment: @NikhilGhuse
I have taken your example.
Only I add these steps:
In HomeController: using pruebaNikhil.Models;
In ModelCS: using System.Data.SqlClient;
                    using System.Data;

The error in the browser is before I pick the button Click:

Comment: jquery-2.1.4.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
json2.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
jquery-2.1.4.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
json2.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Index:50 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at Index:50

Comment: It will parse that json data

Comment: Dear you need to add there references

Comment: Ok, my fault. Sorry. 
Now I have been installing(json2.js) and updating(jquery.js) these packages: 
<script src="../../scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script src="../../scripts/json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

However although there is not any error. Your example does not return any list or data.

Comment: It is returning list and I have mailed you that sample

Comment: @NikhilGhuse Thank you very much. You can see my new update to help more people :)